# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/test.xlsx (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file

i have given read write permission in manifest file ,but i am getting this exception.

```
       07-17 15:23:47.886: W/System.err(384): java.io.FileNotFoundException:         /data/test.xlsx (Permission denied)
       07-17 15:23:47.906: W/System.err(384):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
       07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):   at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
       07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
       07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
       07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)
        07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):  at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        07-17 15:23:47.915: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        07-17 15:23:47.926: W/System.err(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        07-17 15:23:47.936: W/System.err(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        07-17 15:23:47.936: W/System.err(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        07-17 15:23:47.936: W/System.err(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        07-17 15:23:47.936: W/System.err(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        07-17 15:23:47.957: W/System.err(384):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can u see file in file expoler ddms ?

Comment: where is /data/test.xlsx located?

Comment: Check if that file really exists in the path you are searching for and if it does, then paste the code you have for accessing that file.

Comment: is your mobile rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/data` is not accessbile from a normal user. Infact if your run from adb

```
adb shell ls /data
```

you will get

```
opendir failed, Permission denied
```

data has the following permission

```
drwxrwx--x system   system            2013-07-16 10:09 data
```

Comment: thanks you are right problem solved by giving right directory